# Looking for a way tu use Cypress fixtures for all my custom commands outside an it block

Tags: cypress

I'm building some custom commands and trying to use my fixtures data for all my commands. Right now I'm forced to define it inside an it block.
Looks similar to this:

```
    it("Commands", () => {

    cy.fixture("fixtureFile").as("data");

    cy.get("@data").then((data) => {

        Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
            cy.visit("/login");
            cy.get('#login-email').type(data.userEmail);
            cy.get('#login-pass').type(data.userPass, {log: false});
            cy.get('.btn').debug().click();
         })

        Cypress.Commands.add('createTagMedia', () => {
            cy.get(".close").click();
            cy.get("#form-field-name").type(data.releaseVersion);
            cy.get(".form-group-adTag > .CodeMirror > .CodeMirror-scroll").type(data.mediaTag);
            cy.get("#media-save-btn").click();
        })
     })
  })
```

This it block is being count as a test case, Is there a better way to pass this for more than one command at the same time?

Comment: Firstly, can I ask why you're forced can you not write a command that returns the fixture data and then just call it in a beforeHook? 

I am also intriguted to know why you're choosing to write your tests like this, in the way of an `it` with commands inside of it. It doesn't scream "best practice" to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to learn the best way to write commands, not tests. I don't have much experience writing javascript / cypress stuff. If you could, can you show me how the solution you proposed looks like? I'm trying to write commands, not tests. Thank you!

Comment: Okay i'll have a think. However initially if you're trying to write commands you don't need it blocks. 
You don't need that global "it" block called "Commands" the commands blocks should sit completely on there own in the file you're importing them through. 

Test data (fixtures) ideally in a best practice world should be isolated per test. If the test data is the same for every test then using hooks would be the best way to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found was to put everything inside a before block, for example:

```
    before(() => {

      cy.fixture("fixtureFile").as("data");

      cy.get("@data").then((data) => {

        Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
            cy.visit("/login");
            cy.get('#login-email').type(data.userEmail);
            cy.get('#login-pass').type(data.userPass, {log: false});
            cy.get('.btn').debug().click();
         })

        Cypress.Commands.add('createTagMedia', () => {
            cy.get(".close").click();
            cy.get("#form-field-name").type(data.releaseVersion);
            cy.get(".form-group-adTag > .CodeMirror > .CodeMirror-scroll").type(data.mediaTag);
            cy.get("#media-save-btn").click();
        })
     })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you won't use the following:

```
import {data} from '../fixtures/FixtureFile'
```

Considering you have the following JSON file:

```
{
"data": {
 "userEmail": "blah",
 "userPass": "blah",
 "releaseVersion": "1"
 }
}
```

You can include this on your tests, commands (Cypress.custom.commands), etc.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, looks like this: import {locators} from "../fixtures/locators.json" but as I use that on my commands, for example: cy.get(locators.pageLogin.userField).type(data.userEmail); I'm getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageLogin' of undefined

Comment: I need to see your JSON file. The parent should be “locators”. If it is not (and instead “pageLogin”) then use: import {pageLogin} from ... It would be good to use an IDE with intellisense so you would know if there is an error before running the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
before(() => {
  const data = cy.fixture("fixtureFile");

  cy.login(data);

  cy.createTagMedia(data);
})
```

You could literally do something like the above. With your Cypress.Commands in your command.ts or js whichever you're using.

And make the commands take in a parameter. Then the above before hook would just be in your tests.